# Help with a Macro for Corel Draw

Tags: pdf

Can anybody help me with a macro?

I want to save as PDF a multiple page facing page booklet from Corel draw but CorelDraw 2020 not save as Printer's spread mode. I want a macro what can arrange the pages in Printers spreads order.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Page menu to organize your pages, then publish to pdf instead of print.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Where is the page menu, i did not found in CDR2020?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was using CorelDraw 2021, which contains the separate Page feature.

Comment: The 2020 version does have Pages in the Object Panel. If you rename the pages in their current order, you can keep track of them when you move them around to the order you want. When you rename them, they will have the page # in the panel plus a colon and the original page number, (i.e., if you rename page 3 to the number 3, it will end up looking like 3:3). When you move page 3 to the 5th page position in the panel it will have the name 5:3. You can export to pdf where you can specify the pages to export.

Comment: @nocturns2 Ok, i have renamed, but when i export in the PDF all pages appears as a single pages and not in facing pages order.